# Javascript Is it possible to declare functions in a return?

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

According to this article (https://www.intertech.com/Blog/encapsulation-in-javascript/) the following code is an example of encapsulation in JS. What it does is basically restrict the possibility of modifying the variable fullName, so only if the new fullName does not have numbers it can be changed.

```
  var person = (function () {

  var fullName = "Jason Shapiro";
  var reg = new RegExp(/\d+/);

  return {
    setFullName : function (newValue) {
      if( reg.test(newValue) ) {
        alert("Invalid Name");
      }
      else {
        fullName = newValue;
      }
    },
    getFullName : function () {
     return fullName; 
    }
  }; // end of the return
}());

alert(person.getFullName());  // Jim White is printed again.

person.setFullName( 42 ); // Invalid Name; the name is not changed
```

It all seems logic to me, but what I haven't been able to get is how can he call either getFullName or setFullName, if these functions are in the return block.

Comment: It's an [immediately invoked function expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=iife+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=iife+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Note the parents around the expression and the empty pair that "immediately" calls the function. As a result, `person` is an object with those two functions in it after the whole expression is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing too surprising about this example; we just have to break it down.

1. A variable called `person` is being declared.
2. What kind of object is person? Well, it is the result of calling an anonymous function on zero arguments.
3. When that anonymous function is called, it returns an object.
4. The object returned by the function has two properties, `setFullName` and `getFullName`.
5. The object returned by the function is the value of variable `person`. Therefore `person.getFullName` and `person.setFullName` are both valid expressions.

I think the point of confusion may be that you thought the scope of `getFullName` and `setFullName` is restricted to code inside the `return` expression. However, JavaScript is a very dynamic language. Properties can be added to and removed from an object at any time. And it is at run time, not compile time, where the JavaScript interpreter checks for the existence of properties.

Comment: That last paragraph made it all clear for me! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because the object `person` is being initialized with something called *Self-invoking functions*:

```
(function () {
    // body of the function
}());
```

> The anonymous function above will be invoked right after it has been defined. The benefit of self-invoking functions is that they enable us to execute code once without cluttering the global namespace (without declaring any globals). [Reference](http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Therefore, your object right in that moment is being initialized with the returned value.

**In your case, with:**

```
{
    setFullName: function(newValue) {
      if (reg.test(newValue)) {
        alert("Invalid Name");
      } else {
        fullName = newValue;
      }
    },
    getFullName: function() {
      return fullName;
    }
};
```

So, the object `person` will be initialized with those functions and for that reason you will be able to call `getFullName` and `setFullName`.

Answer (score 1):

In `person` variable we have an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), which executes immediately, when the interpreter reaches this line. And this function returns an object, so finally, `person` variable is an object, and as we know, objects can contain functions too, and we can easily invoke functions from this object like so:

```
person.getFullName();
person.setFullName(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're not noticing in the code is its form: a function is declared and immediately run. The value stored in `person` is not a function, but an object containing two functions.

`function () { ... }` is a function.

`(function () { ... )())` is the return value of that function.